# Modify XML text template textfield font_size?

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

My program runs in vb.net/c#.

XML template for printing a document has a textfield_bound with preset font_size. The template works and looks like this

```
More of the same


<textfield_bound
            value_id="order_Note_User"
            x="0"
            y="108"
            width="180"
    height ="12"
            padding="0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5"
            font_size="10" />


More of the same
```

Question is : Is it possible to change the font_size of this XML template programmically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking can you modify the value of an attribute in an xml fragment then yes.
See [Modify a single XML attribute in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221259/modify-a-single-xml-attribute-in-c-sharp)
It's not clear whether the template is a file or not (I'm guessing yes) so you'll need
to load it into a XmlDocument object first, perform the update and then save, but all quite do-able. What is the textfield_bound part of - some 3rd party app or something?

Comment: No it is just a a custom made document, that has not traditional text distribution to print. We use textfields to fill with customer informations and when the Note is too short its hard to read sometimes. Therefore we want to make it bigger for easier handling.